# Excel Macro to change layout of the file

Tags: excel, vba, unpivot

I have the following data in excel:

[image]

I need help writing a macro that will help me change the layout and create a new file.
The new layout that I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with Power Query.

Load the table into the Query editor. To do that, select the data, then click the **Data** Ribbon > **From Table/Range** in the "**Get & Transform**" group.

The data will be loaded into the Power Query editor. Select the first column and then click the **Transform** ribbon command "**Unpivot other columns**". Rename the resulting columns as desired and save the query. It will load the result into a table in a new worksheet.

If you want the result in a new file, you can start from a new file and use **Get Data > From File > From Workbook** in the **Data** ribbon to load the data from the Excel source file. Navigate to the sheet you want to load and then unpivot as described above.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub trans()
    Dim WB As Workbook, toWb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vResult()
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    
    myPath = WB.Path & "\"
    
    Set Ws = WB.ActiveSheet
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        For j = 2 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To 3, 1 To n)
            vResult(1, n) = vDB(i, 1)
            vResult(2, n) = vDB(1, j)
            vResult(3, n) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Set toWb = Workbooks.Add
    Set toWs = toWb.Sheets(1)
    With toWs
        .Range("a1").Resize(1, 3) = Array("Date Time", "WellNo", "WellValue")
        .Range("a2").Resize(n, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vResult)
    End With
    toWb.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & "myResult"
    toWb.Close (0)
            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Unpivot

- The following will return only the resulting data, headers excluded, in a worksheet.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub unPivot()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1" ' Including headers.
    Const lrCol As Variant = "A"
    Const cCount As Long = 7
    Const repCount As Long = 1
    
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const tgtFirst As String = "A2" ' Excluding headers.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Range ('rng').
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rCount As Long
    rCount = lRow - ws.Range(srcFirst).Row + 1
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(srcFirst).Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array ('Source').
    
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = rng.Value
    
    ' Write values from Source Array to Target Array ('Target').
    
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(1 To rCount * (cCount - repCount), 1 To repCount + 2)
    
    Dim cVal As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim l As Long
    
    For i = 2 To rCount
        For j = 1 + repCount To cCount
            k = k + 1
            For l = 1 To repCount
                Target(k, l) = Source(i, l)
            Next l
            Target(k, l) = Source(1, j)
            Target(k, l + 1) = Source(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    If k = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write values from Target Array to Target Range.
    
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    With ws.Range(tgtFirst).Resize(, repCount + 2)
        ' Clear contents below header row.
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - ws.Range(tgtFirst).Row + 1).ClearContents
        ' Write values.
        .Resize(k).Value = Target
    End With

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```